# Evaluate mathematical expression from String - Python

Tags: python, string, expression, eval, evaluate

I need to evaluate an expression from a string given such as "(19 + ((91 -96)-13))" but I have to make te algorithm myself, which I can't use eval() or something similar.

I've been tried alot with this code but it gives me problems with negative numbers:

```
while counter < 1:
    chunks = []
    counter2 = 1

    for character in operation:
        if character.isdigit():
            if chunks[-1].isdigit():   # If the last chunk is already a number
                chunks[-1] += character  # Add onto that number
            else:
                chunks.append(character) # Start a new number chunk
        elif character in '+-/*()':
            chunks.append(character)  # This doesn't account for `1 ++ 2`.

    for e in reversed(chunks):
        if e == '(':
            counter2 = len(chunks) - counter2
            break
        else:
            counter2 = counter2 + 1

    if chunks[counter2+2] == '+':
        result2 = int (chunks[counter2+1]) + int (chunks[counter2+3])
    elif chunks[counter2+2] == '-':
        result2 = int (chunks[counter2+1]) - int (chunks[counter2+3])
    elif chunks[counter2+2] == '*':
        result2 = int (chunks[counter2+1]) * int (chunks[counter2+3])
    elif chunks[counter2+2] == '/':
        result2 = int (chunks[counter2+1]) / int (chunks[counter2+3])


    chunks[counter2] = ''
    chunks[counter2 + 1] = ''
    chunks[counter2 + 2] = str (result2)
    chunks[counter2 + 3] = ''
    chunks[counter2 + 4] = ''

    operation = ''.join(chunks)
```

Don't pay attention to the while condition, I'm updating it as I need just to check

Comment: Using a proper lexing-parsing tool like [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) or even Lex/Yacc would make your life a lot easier...

Comment: the thing is I can not, I have to make the whole algorithm..

Comment: What specific problems with negative numbers are you experiencing with this code?

Comment: for example if it's (-5-6) it won't do it correctly because it'll take the '-' instead of the number, i even got stuff like (9+-18)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to debug code more on your own. The problem you have is the int conversion is being done on "-" and not "-5". You need to combine "-" and integer next in the sequence and convert that to int and use.
    temp = str(chunks[counter2+3]) + str(chunks[counter2+4])

Comment: i fixed that somehow but now it gives weird results